# SAP document flow - Reading a value using Sap Gui Scripting

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have a question that I just cant find an answer for anywhere !

I'm trying to get the value of the Shipment number highlighted in red below using SAP GUI scripting and VBA, as the results need to be saved on an excel sheet.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this with SAP GUI scripting. Can anyone please assist with this?

There are no other SAP transactions that any of my colleagues are aware of that can give a different view e.g grid containing this information, nor is there any that i can enter the purchase order number to get the shipment number.

In my search for a solution i saw suggestions including SE11 or SQL trace. Unfortunately I don't have access to these or other super user/ developer tools.

So SAP gurus out there, please help. :)

cheers

[image: SAP DOCUMENT FLOW]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up clicking on the magnifying glass icon on the top left and there was a field in the next page that had the number.I then had to figure out how to read it which i did :)